# Using javascript location.search within an iFrame

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to determine of the url has a query string which includes 'pid' which works... but

```
if ( location.search ){
   var pid = location.search.replace("?","").split("=");
   if ( pid[0] === "pid" )
   {
      document.getElementById("headline").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

But how to make it work from within an iFrame?

It would need to read the document.referrer url to see if there is a query string with 'pid'

Comment: Have you tried using `window.parent.location` instead of just `location`?

Comment: I tried wndow.parent.location and it works, but not with cross-domain iFrames. document.referrer works through iFrames cross-origin but how to integrate that with location.search ?

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Are you trying to see if the `document.referrer` url had a query string that appears in `window.parent.location.href`?

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe src attribute? If so, you could add the pid from the parent page to the query string of the iframe src URL and pick it up in your iframe code.

Comment: @ellitt Just trying to compare if a  document.referrer url has the query string with 'pid' or not. If it does,  then I will hide some content... can I incorporate the document.referrer somewhere in the code to make that work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly and all you care to know is if the `document.referrer` contains the string "pid" anywhere, then you could try this:

```
if (document.referrer.includes("pid")) {
  document.getElementById("headline").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: yea, that works! I didn't realize that would work. What if 'pid' happens to be part of the domain or other part of the url, and not part of a query string? I wouldn't want that to determine the inclusion of 'pid' only if it was part of the query string.

Comment: This should work: `document.referrer.split("?", 2)[1].includes("pid")`

Comment: You would just use `document.referrer.split("?", 2)[1].includes("pid")` in the `if` instead of `document.referrer.includes("pid")`.

Comment: I am running into an issue and getting an error if the url's query string does not include 'pid' with this if else statement—do you know what would fix it ?

function colorchange() {
 if (document.referrer.split("?", 2)[1].includes("pid")) {
             console.log("pid pm");
} else {
 console.log("standard pm");
}
};